# The new project type and template does not show up after installing VSIX package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I have developed a VSPackage for Visual Studio. I followed all the instructions in these walkthroughs:

[Part 1 - Creating a Basic Project System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961.aspx)

[Part 2 - Creating a Basic Project System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826178.aspx)

Everything works fine when I debug the project: I see a new project type defined by me under the Installed Templates.

[image]

**Problem**

However when I deploy this VSIX installer to the *Visual Studio Gallery* or install it manually, I don't see the template and the new project type.

**Question**

How can I make this work when deploying?

**Note**

What I want is a VSPackage that when you install, it will add a new project type and adds some other menu commands to the menu bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this doing these steps by:

- Adding the generated `.zip` template from the `bin/debug` folder to my project in Visual Studio.
- Then adding this file as an asset to the `.vsixmanifest` file.
- Finally rebuilt the solution and deployed the `.vsix` file to the *Visual Studio Gallery*.

**Note** These steps were not mentioned in the MSDN walkthroughs.